# What does "these things" specifically refer to in Matthew 21:23?

Tags: matthew

> Matthew 21:23
> Jesus entered the temple courts, and, while he was teaching, the chief priests and the elders of the people came to him. "By what authority are you doing **these things**?" they asked. "And who gave you this authority?"

Answer (score 3):

What does "these things" (ταῦτα) specifically refer to in Matthew 21:23?

In context of Matthew 21:23, the chief priests ( ἀρχιερεῖς) are questioning events that occurred in the temple (ἱερὸν) during the previous day:

1. He Overturned ( κατέστρεψεν) the seats (καθέδρας ) of those selling doves. [Matthew 21:12]
2. He Healed ( ἐθεράπευσεν) the blind ( τυφλοὶ) and the lame ( χωλοὶ). [Matthew 21:14]

We are to presume Yeshua (Jesus) of Nazareth returns to continue His temple reforms the next day based on Matthew 21:18 which states "in the morning (Πρωῒ ) then, having come back ( ἐπανάγων) into the city". - Then after returning to the temple in Matthew 21:23, Yeshua is questioned about His authority to do "these things" (ταῦτα ) specifically overturning seats as well as healing the blind & lame.